# check if a list has all nulls

Tags: java, jstl

I have a list of beans that has properties in it. I'm building 2 subLists to see whats in them and passing to a page.

I need to do a check to see if all the values in either 2 sublist's are all nulls

Java:

```
beans = dao.getResourceExpended(filter);
List<BigDecimal> scheduledBeans = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
List<BigDecimal> realBeans = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
for (ResourceBean f : beans)
{
    scheduledBeans.add(f.getScheduledResource());
    realBeans.add(f.getRealResource());
}

request.setAttribute("scheduledBeans", scheduledBeans);
request.setAttribute("realBeans", realBeans);
```

JSTL:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty scheduledBeans}">
        alert("scheduledBeans Empty");
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${empty realBeans}">
        alert("realBeans Empty");
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

The "choose" above does not work because the values come back as:

```
alert("scheduledBeans =" +  scheduledBeans);
alert("realBeans =" +  realBeans);
```

- `scheduledBeans = [null, null, null]`
- `realBeans = [null, null, null]`

Comment: show code where you set this two arrays into request or into session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't add `null` values to the list.

Replace

```
scheduledBeans.add(f.getScheduledResource());
realBeans.add(f.getRealResource());
```

by

```
if (f.getScheduledResource() != null) {
    gescheduledBeans.add(f.getScheduledResource());
}
if (f.getRealResource() != null) {
    realBeans.add(f.getRealResource());
}
```

If they are all `null`, then the list stays empty and then the `empty` test will pass.